# Spyder/Anaconda not installed properly. How do I find it?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, spyder

I have tried installing anaconda multiple times on my Windows’s 10 laptop however, when I look for it after installation in the start menu it isn’t there? 
Neither is spyder? I tried downloading win python but that didn’t work either. Any help would be much appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

For a standard installation you should have this folder

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.anaconda\navigator\scripts
```

If so, start `anaconda-navigator-app.bat` and see if it works.

P.S.: I really can't recommend Spyder anymore, since it has multiple problems especially if you might work with Qt. VS Code seems to be a better alternative.

Comment: On Windows 7, I've also seen it in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` or `C:\Anaconda3`. Not sure about Windows 10.

Comment: I searched on my computer (Windows 10) and found it in this folder, so I guess that's the standard place for it in win10

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I actually ended up installing it once more and it still doesn't come up in the search tool on the start bar however, if you look for apps in start it is there.

Comment: That's actually a Windows problem; the search doesn't find anything anymore, not even Microsoft apps